# Azure Cosmos MongoDB doesn't seem to use Index

Tags: mongodb, azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I am Using Azure Cosmos MongoDB with 2 Collections and when trying to query on a part of the primary Key like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { $match: 
    {"_id.product_id": "1258"}
  }
],{"explain":true})
```

i receive following informations about index usage:

```
"indexUsage" : {
  "pathsIndexed" : {
    "individualIndexes" : [
      "_id.product_id"
    ],
    "compoundIndexes" : [ ]
  },
  "pathsNotIndexed" : {
    "individualIndexes" : [ ],
    "compoundIndexes" : [ ]
  }
}, ...
"queryMetrics" : {
  "retrievedDocumentCount" : 603,
  "retrievedDocumentSizeBytes" : 415786,
  "outputDocumentCount" : 1,
  "outputDocumentSizeBytes" : 470,
  "indexHitRatio" : 0,
  "totalQueryExecutionTimeMS" : 5.35,
  "queryPreparationTimes" : {
    "queryCompilationTimeMS" : 0.11,
    "logicalPlanBuildTimeMS" : 0.06,
    "physicalPlanBuildTimeMS" : 0.15,
    "queryOptimizationTimeMS" : 0.02
  },
  "indexLookupTimeMS" : 0,
  "documentLoadTimeMS" : 3.59,
  "vmExecutionTimeMS" : 4.8099,
  "runtimeExecutionTimes" : {
    "queryEngineExecutionTimeMS" : 1.2099,
    "systemFunctionExecutionTimeMS" : 0.37,
    "userDefinedFunctionExecutionTimeMS" : 0
  },
  "documentWriteTimeMS" : 0.01
}
```

the index on "_id.product_id" seems to be getting used but the indexHitRatio remains at 0
at this point the query duration seems to be fine but in the productive database the duration gets to the point of Mongo Timeouts because of the amount of data

i have tried :
reindexing; dropping and rebuilding the entire collection; adding wildcard indexex to basically every possiblity; adding simple type indexes to very field

is there anything im doing wrong within Cosmos as it is technially not the exact same as MongoDB?

==============================EDIT==========================

is there any problem in trying to index parts of an object primary key?

Comment: This should work. It is supported. I would normally say you may want to rebuild your index but you've already done that and more. I wish I had something else you could try. Only thing I can think of is to raise a support ticket so an engineer can look more closely at your collection.

Comment: Perhaps the collection is so small that the server decides it will be faster to just load the documents rather than consult an index.

Comment: @Joe the collection in productive is about 5gb and needs almost a minute to do a simple query even with all the indexes applied and the logs show that the index should be used

Comment: @MarkBrown i mgiht try that, i havent found anything else that could be wrong with the database or the collection